# In open-list systems, how do individual candidates promote themselves while being a team player?

Tags: voting-systems, campaigning, proportional-representation

In [open-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_list) systems, political candidates are expected to promote their party platform while simultaneously advocate for a personal mandate so they can rise higher on the list.

This might create a dilemma since personal campaigning could harm party cohesion. Yet each candidate subconsciously knows that they have to "out compete" their own team member.

So how do political candidates advocate for themselves while remaining a team player in open-list systems?